# Django - Sendgrid how to substitute tags using send_mail

Tags: django, sendgrid

I'm looking at the Sendgrid documentation and it writes that to send an email, this is enough:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

If I want to use Sendgrid templates, where do I declare the template I want to use? Also, there are [substitution tags](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html) in Sendgrid's templates. How can I declare them in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment but you might want to consider using [`sendgrid-django`](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django) which allows easy usage of your sendgrid templates.